# Prepare rough surface for cabinetry

Tags: hardwood-floor, mounting

I would like to make some hardwood file cabinets as the supports for a desk in my study.

The problem is that the floor of the study is "softscraped" wood flooring which has very rough texture to it. So, I am concerned about setting down a flat planed hardwood cabinet base on this uneven surface.

Is there some approach to mating the two surfaces or using an intermediate material of some kind, like maybe a rubber matting that would ensure a good surface to surface contact that will leave both sides in perfect condition?

Comment: Big ol' self-adhesive felt pads. Cut them to shape if your cabinet supports are narrow.

Comment: I've seen the felt pads sold in a big 5"x7" sheet (maybe bigger?).  The sheet can be cut into strips with a razor knife.